# Sign in using google with user-defined image on button

Tags: jquery, .net, model-view-controller

This code works fine when I can't use user-defined image set in google sign-in button.

But I want to set user-defined sign-in using google image.anybody have an idea about this,please post the reply.

```
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com">

<div id="gConnect" style="display:inline-block !important;">
                                <div id="signin-button"></div> 
</div>

//Script

 <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js?onload=startApp" async defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

            var auth2 = {};
            var helper = (function () {
                return {
                    /**
                     * Hides the sign in button and starts the post-authorization operations.
                     *
                     * param {Object} authResult An Object which contains the access token and
                     *   other authentication information.
                     */
                    onSignInCallback: function (authResult) {
                        if (authResult.isSignedIn.get()) {
                            helper.profile();
                        } else if (authResult['error'] || authResult.currentUser.get().getAuthResponse() == null) {
                            console.log('There was an error: ' + authResult['error']);
                            $('#gConnect').show();
                        }
                    },

                    /**
                     * Gets and renders the currently signed in user's profile data.
                     */
                    profile: function () {
                        gapi.client.plus.people.get({
                            'userId': 'me'
                        }).then(function (res) {
                            var profile = res.result;
                            var EmailId = profile.emails[0].value;
                            var FullName = res.result.name.givenName;
                            var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
                            auth2.signOut().then(function () { });

                            linkedinData=res;
                            flag="G";

                            $.post('@Url.Action("CheckEmailLogin","Home")',{Email:EmailId,type:flag},function(data){
                                if(data.msg=="Already registred.")
                                {
                                    window.location.href = '@Url.Action("SocialLogin", "Home")' + '?UserEMailId=' + EmailId + '&FirstName=' + FullName + '&type=G&UserType='+$("#ddlUserType").val()+'';
                                }
                                else if(data.msg=="Not register");
                                {
                                    $("#DvUserType").modal('show');
                                }
                                if(data.msg=="Email is exist.")
                                {
                                    alert("Email is already registered.");
                                }
                            });
                        }, function (err) {
                            var error = err.result;
                            console.log(erroe);
                            $('#gConnect').show();
                        });
                    }
                };
            })();

            /**
        * Handler for when the sign-in state changes.
        *
        * param {boolean} isSignedIn The new signed in state.
        */
            var updateSignIn = function () {
                if (auth2.isSignedIn.get()) {
                    helper.onSignInCallback(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance());
                } else {
                    helper.onSignInCallback(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance());
                }
            }

            /**
             * This method sets up the sign-in listener after the client library loads.
             */
            function startApp() {
                gapi.load('auth2', function () {
                    gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1').then(function () {
                        gapi.signin2.render('signin-button', {
                            scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
                            fetch_basic_profile: true
                        });
                        gapi.auth2.init({
                            fetch_basic_profile: true,
                            scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
                        }).then(
                              function () {
                                  auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
                                  auth2.isSignedIn.listen(updateSignIn);
                                  auth2.then(updateSignIn());
                              });
                    });
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.

gapi.signin2.render('my-signin2', {
        'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
        'width': 200,
        'height': 50,
        'longtitle': true,
        'theme': 'dark',
        'onsuccess': onSuccess,
        'onfailure': onFailure
      });